# highcharts - do not show zeroes in labels and format

Tags: highcharts

I try to hide the labels for which the values are zero, and at the same time format other labels. This does not look to work properly. I used the property "format" and the "formatter" trick. But combine both does not look to be possible.

```
dataLabels:{
    enabled:true,
    format: "{point.y:.1f}",
    formatter:function(){
        if(this.y > 0)
            return this.y;
        }
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/laloune/p74p2s91/

any idea?

Comment: Using just the `formatter` and then doing the formatting programmatically should do the trick.

Comment: worked like a charm using toFixed(1). fiddle updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must change '0' to 'null' in the dataset.
    http://jsfiddle.net/mnpL7zu4/
`series: [{ data: [11, 71.5, null, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]}]`